# Using Google Drive Api in C# Windows Service Application

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api

I have two different projects related to each other.

In my first project (WinForms), users create their own plans and make some application settings (Schedule, Mail Account Settings, SQL Connection etc.).

My second project (C# Windows Service) takes database backups, compresses and sends e-mails to users using sql connection according to the schedule in my first project. No problem so far.

I want the compressed database backup to be sent via Google Drive Api.

When I run the sample code in my WinForms application, a browser is triggered and asks me to login to google account. It then works correctly. But the same code is not working in my windows service application. I think I am not getting permissions because a browser is not triggered. What do you think is the best way to implement this scenario?

Please your help. I am sharing the sample code below.

```
  private static UserCredential GetCredentials()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream =
               new FileStream("C:/MyApp/GoogleApis/credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = "token.json";
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }
    }



    private static void UploadBasicFile(string path, DriveService service)
    {
        var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        fileMetadata.Name = Path.GetFileName(path);
        fileMetadata.MimeType = "image/jpeg";
        FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
        using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
        {
            request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
            request.Fields = "id";
            request.Upload();
        }

        var file = request.ResponseBody;

    }
```

*Projects do not exist in the same solution.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think I am not getting permissions because a browser is not triggered.

That is exactly what's happening. Windows services run in the background, so the user is not being prompted to authencation the application.

Your Winforms application is running on the users machine I assume, the windows service is probably also ruining on the users machine.  Which means that the windows service service should be able to read the same authorization code that your winforms application does.

The question is why isnt it.

Lets look your code.

This is a pretty standard example for Oauth2 with an installed application.  By default it is using FileDataStore to store the users credentials.  In credPath under the name of "user"

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
```

Assuming you are using this exact same code the windows service should be picking it up.  If its not then my guess is that its the permissions on the windows service it needs permission to read from that directory.

So to start.

1. check to be sure your using the exact same credPath and "user" in your windows service.
2. Check that the windows service can read the file in credPath.

When properly configured your user should only need to authorize your application through WinForms and the windows service should be able to read the user credentials from that.